# How would encrypted search engine work, a search engine where it doesn't know what was searched for

Tags: encryption, privacy, search-engines

I took course on cryptography on coursera, and the instructor said that it's possible to create search engine as so that even search engine wont know what you searched for but it will be able to find results.

i can think of one way but that's just unrealistic.

Comment: A little more context might help. Coursera has multiple cryptography courses. Which course was it, and at what point did the instructor say this? More specifically, was the instructor discussing a specific encryption scheme/technique? Please [edit] that into your question.

Comment: [How to Search on Encrypted Data: Searchable Symmetric Encryption](http://outsourcedbits.org/2014/08/21/how-to-search-on-encrypted-data-searchable-symmetric-encryption-part-5/)